# Selecting fields of structs inside an array inside a dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a [PySpark](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/index.htm) dataframe loaded from a 3 GB json.gz file, with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- quote: string (nullable = true)
 |-- occurrences: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- articleID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to drop the title, author and date fields, or create a new `dataFrame` that does not include these fields.

So far I've managed to get the following schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- quote: string (nullable = true)
 |-- occurrences: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- articleID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- source: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

using

```
df.select(df._id, df.quote,
      array(
          struct(
              col("occurrences.articleID"), 
              col("occurrences.source")
          )
      ).alias("occurrences"))
```

But I need a way to keep articleIDs and sources together in the same `struct`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found something that works:

```
clean_df = df.withColumn("exploded",explode("occurrences")).drop("occurrences")
            .select(
                df._id, 
                df.quote,
                df.exploded.articleID.alias("articleID"),
                df.exploded.source.alias("source")
             )
    .withColumn("occs", struct(col("articleID"), col("source")))
    .groupBy("_id", "quote").agg(collect_set("occs").alias("occurrences"))
```

But if anyone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it, since this seems very round-about. (And as a sidenote, collect_set only seems to works with java 8.)